# Get active window title in X11 Haskell library

Tags: haskell, x11, xorg

I am trying to extract the title of the currently active window using 
[X11](https://www.stackage.org/lts-15.2/package/X11-1.9.1) library.

I was trying to inspire myself with the [xdotool code](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/xdo.c) but I got stuck after `getWindowProperty32` returned `Foreign.C.Types.CLong` that I couldn't handle in any way.

I know I could just create a new process with `xdotool` and read its output, but this is not the thing I am going to achieve. How can I do it via direct X server communication in Haskell?

Comment: Does [fetchName](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.2/X11-1.9.1/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#v:fetchName) not do what you want?

Comment: Yes! But only together with getInputFocus which I found nearby the fetchName. You may post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using [`getInputFocus`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.2/X11-1.9.1/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Misc.html#v:getInputFocus) and [`fetchName`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.2/X11-1.9.1/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#v:fetchName).

The code would look something like

```hs
getActiveWindowTitle :: Display -> IO (Maybe String)
getActiveWindowTitle display = do
  (window, _) = getInputFocus display
  fetchName display window
```